# How can I "Modularise" or Create a separation of containers within an Winforms application

Tags: winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I'm starting to build a winforms app and it will end up having a lot of different forms for various things.  I am using Devexpress controls but I guess this could apply to any WinForms app.

I have a single form which has a devexpress navigation frame on it and this navigation frame is a container of sorts with pages that represent the different "screens"  pretty basic and just a prototype. [image] .

One way of doing this is to add screeen after screen to the navigation frame - but that doesn't feel like good practice.  I would like to have each "page" of the navigation frame loaded from a separate user control or form so I can keep the code separate and easier to maintain.

How to I achieve that? Maybe I need to rethink what I am doing.

Comment: `Visual Inheritance` might be what you are after, be aware though that although c#  does this perfect, this thing they call a designer in VS has much problems with it

Comment: No I’m moving away from OOP - probably just looking at assigning a user control as a child or something

Comment: `No I’m moving away from OOP` That will make your live much more difficult, success

Comment: Maybe - but makes life better in so many other ways.  Removes so many bugs.  I first switched away from OOP while using nodejs and since switching to F# I have very few bugs in my code.  It is such a breath of fresh air.